# How to specify the periodicity of an angular predictor (`sun_altitude`) in a regression model?

Tags: r, angle, periodicity

I am using the package `momentuHMM` in R, which analyses data using Hidden Markov Models. However, coefficient estimates are calculated using linear regressions.

If I would want to use `Hour` (format: 24 h) as a predictor variable  of a given `Y`dependent variable, I should specify `Y ~ cosinor(Hour, period = 24)`. The cosinor function automatically incorporates both the `sin()` and `cos()` as well as their interaction.

I wonder which value I should indicate in `period` of the mentioned function `cosinor()` if I use the variable `sun_altitude`, for which values range between -1.3 (night) and 1.2 (midday). What should I indicate in `period`? 2.5?. My doubt comes because `Hour` and `sun_altitude` are different in the sense that for `Hour`, after the value `23`, the next value is `00`, so the maximum and minimum value of this predictor is closer that, for instance, `00` and `12`. However, it is not the same with `sun_altitude`, since a value of `0` and a value of `1.2` are closer than between `1.2` and `-1.2`. That is, for `sun_altitude` the maximum and minimum value of the variable are not closer between them than between the minimum and medium values.

Should I consider that when specifying `period`?

Below I show some code to create a dataframe with `sun_altitudes` just in case someone wants to take a look:

```
df <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-07-29 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC"), as.POSIXct("2016-07-31 23:45:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC"), "15 min")
df<- as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df)<- c("Round_datetime15")
df[2]<-getSunlightPosition(date=df$Round_datetime15, lat= 37.6, lon=-0.65, keep = ("altitude"))[4]
range(df$altitude)
```

Note: maximum and minimum values of the sun altitude are not reached in one day. The maximum value of the sun is reached in summer and the minimum value in winter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'm posting this as an answer.

It is not clear to me why you would include a periodic effect of sun altitude in that situation. As you mention in the case of the time of day, a periodic effect should be considered when the two ends need to match (e.g., the effect of time of day should be very similar at 23:59 and 00:00). From what you write, it doesn't sound like the effect of sun altitude should match at -1.3 and 1.2, so I don't think that you need the `cosinor` function.

So, I think you can just include the covariate as is in your formula, i.e., `~ sun_altitude`.